# Design of my widget is not appearing as it should

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm currently working on an inventory system and have gotten it working for the most part. The only problem is, when I try and start the game, the design gets warped with no color in the border and the button being misplaced.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
The individual squares are inventory slots and look normal like how they are supposed to. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: That looks indeed wrong, but I'm missing some context here: How do you add it to the screen? Is it being placed in a CanvasPanel? Can you show that as well? If you have it placed in a CanvasPanel, have you checked "Size to Content" in the Slot, because it looks like the layout space is reduced to the default 100x30?
Have you used the [Widget Reflector](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Slate/WidgetReflector/) to see what's going on with the layout of the individual elements?

Comment: @MaxPlay I have made the border a child to a size box, not used a canvas panel and I've added a couple of extra screenshots too hoping that it might help. I haven't used the widget reflector yet.

Comment: In the screenshots below, you are indeed adding it to a canvas panel. I can see that you didn't use a CanvasPanel _in_ the widget, but you added it as a child _to_ a CanvasPanel.

I'd suggest setting the "SetAutoSize" to true in the third screenshot and see if it helps.

Comment: oh, didn't realise I was, very much a complete noob at game dev and I'm following a tutorial. I'm learning as the tutorial goes but thank you so much, it got fixed.